# Any way to get Spotify Artist's header image?

Tags: javascript, php, spotify

Is there any way to get the image used for the background of an artist page in PHP or JS? It's different from the normal artist image, so I don't think it's included in the artist JSON from the API.

Example on an artist page:

[image]

The link for this image can be found by inspecting the elements of an artist page and searching "artist-header", which is the element with the image as a background-image.

I tried simply loading the artist's open.spotify page, searching for the "artist-header" class, then taking the background-image style attribute. However, for some reason calling `file_get_contents()` on the artist's page returned a completely different page. This page did not contain the background image.

Comment: It's going through a CDN. Maybe there's a step in between to stop this automated scraping?

Answer (score 3):

The artist header image is now at:

```
document.querySelector('div[data-testid="background-image"]').style.backgroundImage.slice(5, -2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Open the profile of the artist you're nabbing the cover banner from on your browser and fire up the inspect/developer tools interface. Hit CTRL-F and type in 'background', scroll a little through the results, and when you get to the line seen in the screenshot attached, copy and paste the url within the brackets into a new tab, and voila! All yours to save and customise.

[Screenshot of Spotify artist profile of *808 State*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HinwQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<element>.style["<parameter>"]` to get to the contents of `<element>`'s style.
It also allows you to change that value.

---

Extracting link to the image:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('artist-header')[0].style["background-image"].slice(5,-2)
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I mentioned I tried, however using file_get_contents() returns a different page.